# nodejs application hosted from sub-folder on azure websites

Tags: node.js, angularjs, azure

I'm hoping somebody can help me here. I am very new to NodeJS and am trying to deploy a basic sample website created from the Angular seed project to an Azure website via git deploy.
The issue i'm having is that I don't understand how to configure the "root" of my application once it is deployed to Azure. My folder structure looks like this:

-app
--js
--css
--index.html
-scripts
--web_server.js

When I run locally, i just cd to my app folder and then start the web_server.js script with node from there.

When it deploys to Azure, it somehow finds the web_server.js file and starts node. But now I have to browse specifically to the app subfolder to view my site. I don't want to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you need node.js if you are deploying to Azure?

Comment: If you specify the folder to deploy using the instructions [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-aspnet-or-aspnet-core-project-file), either in a `.deployment` file or in App Settings, the application in the folder you specify will deploy to ``wwwroot` rather than being in a subfolder. This might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using a `package.json` file in the root and pointing it to your site; use `main` or `binaries` to point to the subdirectory's JS file.

Azure Web Sites will use that information to find your `scripts/web_server.js` then, though it might be easier just to root it all at the top, at least to get things rolling.

See also: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html